# Fixing mojom error after Chrome update

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I wish there was some way to intercept new Chrome(driver) errors in SeleniumWebdriver before they hit my tests. The latest I have found is this one. Does anyone have a fix?

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12819/devtools/ ...
Error:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser
```

The error message above is seen when simply trying to click on a browser input element. Previously it worked fine. Still works fine in IE: but as per the message Chrome cannot interact and the test fails.

Background info for the test

```
NUnit Console Runner 3.4.1 
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1) on port 49205
Only local connections are allowed.
```

I guess that this post isn't in the best format for StackOverflow, and I apologise for that. It's another day in which I found a previously working test has been broken by an update which I hoped could be fixed by updating all framework components, but it wasn't fixed. Sad times!

If anyone else out there using Chromedriver in SeleniumWebdriver has seen the same error msg crop up and has a fix, I would love to hear it.

Comment: If the post isn't in the best format, why not edit it into a better one? Particularly: are you more interested in preventing Chromedriver updates until you know they won't break your tests, or in making sure everything is up to date no matter what?

Comment: I want to use an up to date version of Chrome, and I want to know what the fix is that others are using. A search of the web shows that my problem is not unique, but I did not see a clear answer. I would appreciate any format improvements to the question that anyone can offer. I always try to make my problem scenarios clear.